# How to share Safari full page screenshot to my app through shareExtension

Tags: ios, safari, screenshot, share-extension

This is my `Plist`:

[image]

With this configuration, when sharing Safari full page screenshot via `shareExtension`, my app cannot be seen in the sharing list. How can I solve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same challenge, any solution yet ?

Comment: I achieved it through the predicate string: NSExtensionActivationRule:string,then:
SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.data"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
                ).@count >= 1
                ).@count == 1

Comment: I answered this question below, putting the picture and the content to be filled in.

Comment: In the first try, it works for safari full-page screenshot. I will test with other share function. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FuS7.png)

```
SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.data"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
                ).@count >= 1
                ).@count == 1
```

Comment: Any thought about sharing more than 1 attachment, I tried to make this count bigger in number, app shows in share Menu but multiple assets not getting passed to host app.